# SQL Server 2014: How to write Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, case-when

In my project I am using SQL Server 2014. I stuck where I need following result.

I have these table entries:

[image]

And the expected result is:

[image]

I want to merge unique id's row values in single row having value = 1.

Row values will always be 0 or 1.

I tried many `CASE WHEN` but I am not able to get expected result.

Please suggest.

Comment: what's the logic behind it? Highest column value for each unique id?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, yes thats the logic. always pick row with 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work- Please try.

```
select DISTINCT id,
        MAX(A) OVER (PARTITION BY id) A,
        MAX(B) OVER (PARTITION BY id) B,
        MAX(C) OVER (PARTITION BY id) C
 from tableName
```

Comment: This is more accurate due to DISTINCT. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `A`, `B`, and `C` are some numeric data types you want something like this

```
 select id,
        max(A) as A,
        max(B) as B,
        max(C) as C
 from your_table
 group by id
```

If `A`, `B`, and `C` data type is `bit` then cast it first

```
 select id,
        max(cast(A as int)) as A,
        max(cast(B as int)) as B,
        max(cast(C as int)) as C
 from your_table
 group by id
```

Comment: This might fail if OP stores A/B/C as bools. Other than that it's the solution OP is looking for!